# C# Problem with reading a single column of database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

Im making a tool for reading out TeamSpeak-Clients data.

There is a file named settings.db i know how to read it but not properly.

Here is a image of the database file:

[settings.db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPMgF.png)

I want to define strings like:

```
string last_server = reader["LastUsedServer"];
string last_username = reader["LastUsedServerNickName"];
```

etc...

The problem is, that i only get the first value and if try this:

```
aio_ts_console.Text += reader["LastUsedServer"].ToString();
```

i get this error:

[My Code + Error-Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QavaM.png)

Translated: "The index was outside the array range"

I tried it over and over again (since 3 Hours) but i cant solve the problem, maybe you guys can help me.

**Thank you**

Comment: Your reader doesn't have a column named `LastUserServer` which is why you are getting the error.  The column name is `key` according to your screen shot.  You will have to loop through the data and use an `if`, probably to get the value you want.  Something like this:  `if (reader["key"].ToString() == "LastUserServer") aio_ts_console.Text += reader["value"].ToString();`

Comment: You mean like this? http://prntscr.com/n3838j

Comment: i found the solution: if (reader["key"].ToString() == "LastUserServer") aio_ts_console.Text += reader[2].ToString();  Thank you

Comment: It is wrong solution. It should be `if (reader["key"].ToString() == "LastUserServer") aio_ts_console.Text += reader["value"].ToString();`